# How do I get to the place of power that Cecil Burdon mentioned?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I've been playing this game for a few hours now and I got to the point where I need to find a place of power. Cecil Burdon mentioned a place in a forest where a witch used to live. I got to the place but it's on top of a cliff. I went all over around it but I can't see to find any way of getting up there.

Does anybody know how to get up there ?

Thank you in advance for your reply

Answer (score 9):

In the woods, you surely know the place where you have the tower on your right and a smaller lake on your left. The solution is easy: You have to turn left and get past the lake, you will find a small path that actually takes you up to the tower.

Okay, so here's the detailed version:

When you go through the tunnel that connects Vergen to the woods and the crypt, you arrive at the big lake. Directly in front of you is the hill that you have to take:

[image: Step one]

There's only one way to cross the lake, I'm pretty sure you figured that out by now. :) When you arrive at the intersection, take the left path.

[image: Step two]

On your left, you'll to see the small lake:

[image: Step three]

Take these directions:

[image: Step four]

You will see this; go all the way down on the road…

[image: Step five]

… and you will arrive at the tower.

[image: Step six]

I think that's detailed enough. :)

Comment: Throw in a screenshot, too, and you are golden..

Comment: i cant get to that lake :S its in the mist!

Answer (score 3):

I tried your pictures, I was still confused, here is a video to show EXACTLY how to get there, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to go straight across the first lake without going round - when you enter the area, there is a big rock and a tree to your right. Near that is shallow water where you can walk straight across to the hill leading to the tower.

Answer (score 0):

find a place of power here it is

Comment: Could you summarize the video? In this case, if the video is removed, your answer will still be valid.